# Chrome extension auto file upload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a chrome extension.

The chrome extension is installed on server 1.

The chrome extension is supposed to pick a file from a fixed location and send to server 2.

I have the HTML input type file. I want to set the file and then call the submit button

**I need to do this through chrome extension only. Is that possible?**

This project is for internal purpose and I can make chrome security as disabled if required.

Suggestion appreciated.

Comment: You can't do it without user interaction. The alternative is simply accessing the file via its file:// URL using XMLHttpRequest, but that requires the user to enable "allow access to file URLs" in the extension's details on chrome://extensions page and of course the necessary entry in manifest's permissions.